# Bug in calculation "Reputation gained since your last ..."

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

If I get a downvote on one of my posts and then delete this post, I get back my reputation. However, the "Reputation gained since your last ..." will not show the correct value:

Reputation of the day:

[image: Reputation of the day]

Reputation gained since:

[image: Reputation gained since ...]

Reputation tab:

[image: Reputation tab]

These values should be equals because I have visited the reputation tab before I get the first reputation of the day. The downvote and the remove of the answer was an the same day.

UPDATE:

Maybe that is only a problem in stackoverflow.com

Comment: You can't remove the downvote, only the one who cast it can do it. You can only delete the post, I've edited to clarify.

Comment: @ShadowWizard sorry for being so unconcrete. I am not a english native speaker. Your edit is ok.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the value of the *Reputation gained since your last* is cached. Hence, it can be off compared to your actual reputation. This is the same for the site-specific meta for example: its reputation is derived from the main site, but since there is some caching, it will only update every X minutes.

If this is considered a bug or not, I am not sure. There could be some explanation on the tooltip that its value is updated every X minutes, or something like that. At least, its current behavior is confusing due to the fact somewhere else it is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The downvote was yesterday and the deletion of the answer too. The screenshot i made today (12 hours later)! And there is no explanatio in tool tip. So i do not think that this is a chaching problem

Comment: So what is the number on the top of the reputation tab?

Comment: It is also 78 like the green box.

Comment: Is it possible you have some deleted posts?

Comment: This one which was downvoted yes.